# Django 1.6 and Tastypie, joining tables

Tags: sql, django, join, tastypie

Basically I want to join a bunch of tables together and display it, My tables are sort of as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignField(A)

class D(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignField(A)
```

This is the basic structure of my system, I want to join all the tables with the foreign field to the table A.
I want to also be able to display in xml using Tastypie, aka ?format=xml, I have been able to display one table on its own but it seems like it is impossible to do the type of join I want even though it would be a very simple SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this problem elsewhere: http://djangoandlove.blogspot.com/2012/11/tastypie-following-reverse-relationship.html